# Permute a list using Python

Tags: python, loops, permute

I have a list with the following elements: `A,B,C,D,E,F,G`.
They are either suppose to true or false hence represented by `1` and `0` respectively.

I am supposed to get a combinations but the following restrictions stay:

1. Element `C` and F`are to be true in all cases, ie,`1`.
2. When element `A` is true, element `E`, and `G` can be false.
3. When element `B` is true, element `D` can be false.

Comment: _"when element A is true, element E and G can be false"_ does it mean _"E and G can be false or true"_ or _"E and G have to be false"_ ?

Comment: Looks to me like another *can you make my homework* question. I might be wrong (hope so), in which case, can you put what you have tried so far? We can help you from there.

Comment: Sounds like homework. For your own sake, please read [this letter](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not permutations, but product. Also, I interpret restrictions as:

1. C and F cannot be *false*
2. If A is *false*, E and G cannot be *false*
3. If B is *false*, D cannot be *false*

With that, the code is as followed:

```
import pprint
from itertools import product

def myproduct():
    keys = 'abcdefg'
    values = [(0, 1) for k in keys]

    for value in product(*values):
        d = dict(zip(keys, value))
        # Skip: C and F that are 0 (False)
        if d['c'] == 0 or d['f'] == 0:
            continue

        # Skip: When A is false, E and G cannot be false
        if d['a'] == 0 and (d['e'] == 0 or d['g'] == 0):
            continue

        # Skip: When B is false, D cannot be false
        if d['b'] == 0 and d['d'] == 0:
            continue

        yield d  # This 'permutation' is good

for d in myproduct():
    pprint.pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1}
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 0, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1}
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 1, 'g': 0}
{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 1, 'g': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 0}
{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 1, 'g': 0}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 1, 'g': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 0, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 0}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 0, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 1, 'g': 0}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 0, 'f': 1, 'g': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 0}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1}
```

Notes:

- `values` is a list of `(0, 1)`:

  ```
  [(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)]
  ```
- Each `value` is a tuple of 7 numbers such as:

  ```
  (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
  ```
- `d` is a dictionary in which the keys are *a*, *b*, ... and the values are *0* and *1*